# Difference between output of bitwise operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

For some reason, the following two bitwise operations provide different results yet it seems intuitive that they should provide the same result since the masks used should be the same. What am I missing here? Why would the results of using the two masks vary?

```
public class BitShiftTest {

    private long bitString = -8784238533840732024L ;
    private final int MAX_BITS_POSITION = 63 ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitShiftTest bst = new BitShiftTest() ;
        System.out.printf("Before applying mask: %s\n", Long.toBinaryString(bst.bitString));
        System.out.printf("Using Mask 1: %s\n", Long.toBinaryString(bst.clearBitMask(60)));
        System.out.printf("Using Mask 2: %s\n", Long.toBinaryString(bst.clearBitMaskAlternative(60)));
    }

    public long clearBitMask(int position) {
        return bitString & ~(1 << position) ;
    }

    public long clearBitMaskAlternative(int position) {
        return bitString & (0x8000000000000000L >>> MAX_BITS_POSITION - position) ;
    }
}
```

The results produced are

```
Before applying mask: 1000011000011000000111011001100000101000001000000000000010001000
Using Mask 1: 1000011000011000000111011001100000101000001000000000000010001000
Using Mask 2: 0
```

Comment: Don't you modify `bitString` in the first call?

Comment: Sorry. I should have gotten rid of the bitstring modifications in each of the `clearBitMask...` functions. However, I still get the same awkward results

Comment: What results exactly?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a `~` in the alternative method?

Comment: The goal was really not to use the `~`. Not for any specific reason. Just that this is old code that is this way as I am debugging and refactoring it.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `~(1<<position)` and `0x8000000000000000L >>> MAX_BITS_POSITION - position` are equal, but that's not true.

Basically,  you're missing a `~` in the alternative case - otherwise it looks as if you're just trying to extract one bit, not just clear it. It should be:

```
~(0x8000000000000000L >>> MAX_BITS_POSITION - position)
```

But also, as noted by @RolandIllig `1 << position` is actually done in int arithmetic. You're not seeing this in your output because neither the 60th nor 28th bits happen to be set in the long you are masking. `1L << position` fixes this.

Comment: Good ol' precedence! So in reality, `~(1 << position)` should be equivalent to `(0x8000000000000000L >>> (MAX_BITS_POSITION - position))` if the masks are used against similar data types, right?

Comment: Thanks @RolandIllig. It does seem that using `1L` in the mask sorts it out

Answer (score 0):

`1 << 63` is of type `int` and is therefore equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, since the 1 is shifted out of the number. (In other languages the result would be undefined since you shift by more bits than an `int` has.

To fix this, use `1L << 63`, which operates on `long`.

Comment: Thanks Roland. Using `bitString & ~(1L << position)` gives the expected result that `bitString & ~(1 << position)` did not. However, `bitString & (0x8000000000000000L >>> (MAX_BITS_POSITION - position))` still returns an incorrect value despite it seeming similar to `bitString & ~(1L << position)`

Comment: You got the value of [`1 << 63` wrong](http://ideone.com/jOU7Zz). But this isn't being calculated anyway!